# Projection with child entities

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following entity framework query where I got 40 items:

```
context.Questions
  .Where(x =>
    x.Access >= 1 &&
    x.Enabled == true
  ).ToList();
```

Then I tried a projection as follows:

```
context.Questions
  .Where(x =>
    x.Access >= 1 &&
    x.Enabled == true
  ) 
  .Select(x => new {
    Duration = x.Duration,
    Text = x.Text,
    Answers = x.Answers.Select(y => new {
      Correct = y.Correct,
      Text = y.Text
    })
  }).ToList();
```

In this case I get 150 items ... What am i doing wrong?

Basically I need the list of questions and each question to have a list of answers.

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
context.Questions
  .Where(x =>
    x.Access >= 1 &&
    x.Enabled == true
  ) 
  .Select(u => new {
    Duration = u.Duration,
    Text = u.Text,
    Answers = u.Answers.Select(y => new {
      Correct = y.Correct,
      Text = y.Text
    })
  }).ToList();
```

The reason this solved your problem is because before you were using

```
.Select(x => ..)
```

where x=> references your original `.Where(x =>)` so it is referencing your full list of objects, not the filtered list from your where query.

Comment: That seems to solve that particular problem. Why is that? But I get a new problem. Could you, please, check it? It is something that I also had when I tried to solve the initial post. I just posted an update. Thank You